# How secure is Encrypt-And-MAC?

Tags: authentication, hmac, provable-security, mac, authenticated-encryption

From [this popular Crypto.SE thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac), the general feeling is that Encrypt-Then-MAC is the most secure. From the first answer, the poster says that Encrypt-And-MAC provides integrity of the plaintext. If I'm transferring classified data between two parties, then this plaintext integrity should prevent malicious modifications, right? Assuming there are no known-plaintext attacks feasible in this scenario, is Encrypt-And-MAC secure? The thread seems to recommend against it, although I can't see why it would be considered insecure.

Comment: But if I use a cipher in CTR mode, wouldn't that prevent padding oracle attacks? I think they only apply to CBC.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you use HMAC as your MAC and send the same message twice?

Comment: @SEJPM I was going to write it :), it leaks information about the plaintext. Hide it.

Comment: Wouldn't the HMAC be the same both times? Would that lead to known-plaintext attacks?

Comment: If it's actually _classified_ and not just confidential, then you'll need to follow the regulations set forth by the relevant authorities!

Comment: Not that high level :) If it was, then I'd probably know enough crypto not to ask this question .